# Density plot with shaded in 2.5% and 5%

Tags: r, ggplot2

I wanted to try reproducing the following image using R. The objective is to represent one and two sided hypothesis to a .025 and .95 level, similar to the image below:

[image]

I managed to create a shade within quantiles using resources from other questions, but I want it outside the boundaries, not inside. The code:

```
set.seed(1)
draws <- rnorm(1000000)
dens <- density(draws)

q025 <- quantile(draws, .025)
q975 <- quantile(draws, .975)

dd <- with(dens, data.frame(x, y))

library(ggplot2)

qplot(x, y, data = dd, geom="line") +
  geom_ribbon(data = subset(dd, x > q025 & x < q975),
              aes(ymax = y),
              ymin = 0, fill = "red", colour = NA, alpha = 0.5)
```

Generates:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a little clunky but seems to work; note that the fill is not quite perfect.

```
set.seed(1)
draws <- data.frame(x = rnorm(1000000))
q025  <- quantile(draws$x, .025)
q975  <- quantile(draws$x, .975)

ggplot(draws, aes(x)) +
  geom_density() +
  stat_function(fun = dnorm, xlim = c(min(draws$x), q025), geom = "area") +
  stat_function(fun = dnorm, xlim = c(q975, max(draws$x)), geom = "area")
```

Result:

[image]

**EDIT**: here's a slower version with smoother fill.

```
set.seed(1)
draws <- rnorm(1000000)
dd <- data.frame(x = draws, y = dnorm(draws))
q025  <- quantile(draws$x, .025)
q975  <- quantile(draws$x, .975)

ggplot(dd, aes(x, y)) +
  geom_line() +
  stat_function(fun = dnorm, xlim = c(min(draws$x), q025), geom = "area") +
  stat_function(fun = dnorm, xlim = c(q975, max(draws$x)), geom = "area")
```

Result:

[image]